# Relative path to diff/merge tool in gitconfig?

Tags: git

I have set up a dropbox folder with Git command line tools in a portable fashion and in the same dropbox folder structure I also have Beyond Compare 4 which I like to use for diff/merge.

However, the exact place for this dropbox folder on my computers differ due to some policies so I am trying to convince gitconfig to use a relative path to my Beyond Compare tools.

Is this possible?

This is on Windows 10, I assume it might matter.

This is the folder structure:

```
Dropbox
  |
  +-- Tools
       |
       +-- git
       |    |
       |    +-- bin
       |    +-- mingw64
       |         |
       |         +-- etc (folder with gitconfig in it)
       +-- Beyond Compare 4
            |
            +-- bcomp.exe
```

Here's what I tried adding to the gitconfig file:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    cmd = '../../../Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

But this is the output when I try to use it:

```
D:\Temp> git difftool test.txt

Viewing (1/1): 'test.txt'
Launch 'bc' [Y/n]?
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 124: ../../Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at test.txt

D:\Temp>
```

If I place myself in the `etc` directory on the command line and issue this command:

```
"..\..\..\Beyond Compare 4\bcomp.exe"
```

Then Beyond Compare starts so I guess the relative path is correct in relation to the gitconfig/etc.

I tried removing one level of `../` at a time and retrying but get the same error in each case so the path isn't relative to mingw64 or the git directory either.

I assume that the path is used in relation to where my command line is currently at, which would be my repository.

Also note that if I specify the full and exact path to bcomp.exe it works nicely:

```
[difftool "bc"]
    cmd = 'C:/Users/MY-USERNAME/Dropbox/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

I also have a `%DROPBOX%` environment variable set up to point to the root of my dropbox folder so I tried this:

```
[difftool "bc"]
    cmd = '%DROPBOX%/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Gives me a different error message which I take to mean that environment variables are not legal in gitconfig, or perhaps uses a different syntax:

```
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 124: fg: no job control
```

If I try `$DROPBOX` instead of `%DROPBOX%`, I am back to the previous error message:

```
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 124: $DROPBOX/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at a.txt
```

So is it possible to convince git to use a relative path to find the diff tool? If so, relative to what?

Comment: Have you tried using $DROPBOX instead of %DROPBOX%?

Comment: Did now, same error message really as when using the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Git won't try to search/replace environment variables in paths to tools. So I am afraid that is not possible.
Using a relative path won't work either, so you should really use one of those following approaches.

Provided that this is your setup:

- Config PC1: C:/Users/MY-USERNAME/Dropbox/Tools/Beyond Compare
  4/BComp.exe
- Config PC2: D:/Applications/Dropbox/Tools/Beyond Compare
  4/BComp.exe

The possible options are:

1. (my personal suggestion): instead of having the git-config being shared (`.git/config` in repository), you can also setup per-user config (`C:/Users/MY-USERNAME/.gitconfig` on PC1) and there, using an absolute path.
   This will have the advantage of setting up your preferences for all your repositories, adopting the DRY principle.
2. You can probably just have `cmd = 'BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"`, and modify the PATH environment variable to hold the path to BComp.exe as well (`C:/Users/MY-USERNAME/Dropbox/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/` on PC1, `D:/Applications/Dropbox/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/` on PC2).
3. Using Windows 10, you could probably setup a common *symbolic link*, e.g. `C:/Apps/BComp.exe` to point to the right binary on both environments, so that you can hardcode `C:/Apps/BComp.exe` in your config.

Methods 2 and 3 are there for completeness, or think-out-of-the-box solutions. But really, you should consider the first one.